Issue with databricks connect in spark scala application
Hi team I am getting this run time Exception when trying use databricks connect in my application.
val config = new DatabricksConfig().setHost("<host-id>")
                                  .setClusterId("<cluster-id>")
val spark = DatabricksSession.builder().sdkConfig(config).getOrCreate()

build.sbt
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.5.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.5.1" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" % "databricks-connect" % "14.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" % "databricks-sdk-java" % "0.22.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-api" % "3.5.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-connect-client-jvm" % "3.5.1"

exception
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EPOLL_DOMAIN_CLIENT_CHANNEL_TYPE
        at org.sparkproject.io.grpc.netty.UdsNettyChannelProvider.isAvailable(UdsNettyChannelP
    rovider.java:34)
        at org.sparkproject.io.grpc.ManagedChannelRegistry$ManagedChannelPriorityAccessor.isAvailable(ManagedChannelRegistry.java:172)


It's probably the same issue as https://github.com/apache/incubator-uniffle/issues/1548 - you probably have duplicate shaded grpc jars
